# How to get gtksharp refresh widget in event handler?

Tags: mono, gtk#

I am trying to get a label widget to update when a key is pressed.  For some reason cannot get the label text to update, even though the Gtk thread correctly registers the key press (eg, writes the key to console).  This is mono 4.4.0 and gtk-sharp 2.12 on macos.

```
public MainWindow() : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
{
    Build();
    this.KeyPressEvent += ToddlerKeyPressEventHandler;
}

public void ToddlerKeyPressEventHandler (object o, Gtk.KeyPressEventArgs args) {
    Gtk.Application.Invoke(delegate {
        string letter = args.Event.Key.ToString();
        this.letterLabel.Text = letter;
        Console.WriteLine(letter);
        this.letterLabel.QueueDraw();
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you invoking the event handler code? That event will already be executing in the main gtk thread.

Comment: Was trying that to be sure of where the code was executing.  Doesn't work either way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing an attribute. Try this:

```
[GLib.ConnectBeforeAttribute]
public void ToddlerKeyPressEventHandler (object o, Gtk.KeyPressEventArgs args) 
{
    letterLabel.Text = args.Event.Key.ToString ();
}
```

Bear in mind that if the event handler is hooked up to the label widget this won't work unless you also ensure that the "Selectable" property for that label widget is set to true (checked).